# Passing 2-D array to function gives strange error

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pointers

Hi I am trying to create a function, but it gives error

```
  [Error] cannot convert 'float (*)[(((sizetype)(((ssizetype)n) + -1)) + 1)]' to 'float (*)[30]' for argument '1' to 'float vecino_mas_cercano(float (*)[30])'
```

My code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include <fstream>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int n1=30;

float nearest_neighbor(float distances[30][30])
{  float min=distances[0][1];
   int candidates[n1];
   int city=0;

   for (int i=0;i<n1;i++)
   {  candidates[i]=i;
   }

   for (int i=0;i<n1;i++)
   {  for (int &j:candidates)
      {  if (j!=0)
            if (distances[city][j]<min);
            {  min=distances[i][j];
               candidates[i]=0;
               city=j;
            }
      }
   }
   return min;
}

int main()
{
   //Declaración de variables

   int n=30; //número de nodos o cityes


   FILE *d;
   float distance[n][n];
   d =fopen("Oli30.csv","r");//r abrir el archivo que contiene las distances para leerlo

   for(int i=0 ;i<n; i++) //en la matriz distance se guardan los valores de las distances
   {  for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
      {  fscanf(d,"%f",&distance[i][j]);}
   }

   float tau_initial;

   tau_initial=nearest_neighbor(distance);  
   cout << "The result is " << tau_initial;
   return 0;

}
```

I suppose the problem is because distance is set as a pointer, I dont know how to pass this argument in function     nearest_neighbor.

Can somebody explain me how to make this works??

Thank you

Comment: `float[30]` is a completely different type from `float[31]`. Keeping that in mind, how is the compiler supposed to match a parameter of `float[30][30]` with an argument where the bounds depend on a runtime integer (which isn't standard C++)?

Comment: Please notice the function signature of `float nearest_neighbor(float distances[30][30])` is `float nearest_neighbor(float distances**)`

Comment: Just another reason to avoid variable length arrays compiler extensions.

Comment: If you're really committed to C++, you may want to use the Standard Library containers. C-style arrays are a lot more limited.

Comment: OT, `if (distances[city][j]<min);` is somewhat useless with that semi-colon in that position.

Comment: I really hate this brace style :|

Comment: @RSahu: That really didn't fix the formatting.  There are now statements within the same block but with different left-alignment :(

Comment: @BenVoigt, I debated how much of the formatting to clean up. I left it at a point where I could follow the code.

Comment: While I'm not enthusiastic about putting the first statement on the same line as the opening brace that begins the enclosing block, at least now the statements inside the block are uniformly indented (just as they would be if the opening brace were on its own line, or on the end of the preceding line).  That helps me a lot, anyway.

Comment: @DieterLücking the signature is not that; it is `float (*)[30]` which is different to `float **`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`int n = 30;` must be changed to `int const n = 30;`.

As you have it now, `float distance[n][n]` is illegal. Arrays in Standard C++ must have constants for the dimension.

The error message suggests that your compiler is implementing some kind of extension (perhaps similar to C VLAs) for an array with non-constant dimensions, and then it doesn't know how to match that to a function which expects an array of constant dimensions.

Comment: *compile-time* constants, even

Comment: @BenVoigt yeah it's a bit tricky to specify in precise language. In `int x[30]`, `30` is not `const` but it is a constant expression, and as you say, some constant expressions don't qualify. Feel free to edit :)

Comment: same problem with `int n1=30;`

Answer (score 3):

I believe you have an unintentional bug here:

```
     if (distances[city][j]<min); // The if block ends here.
     {  min=distances[i][j];
        candidates[i]=0;
        city=j;
     }
```

You probably meant:

```
     if (distances[city][j]<min)
     {
        min=distances[i][j];
        candidates[i]=0;
        city=j;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be solved by changing the type of the argument of `nearest_neighbor` and `distance` in `main` to `float**`. However, the initialization of `distance` has to be done differently and the actual dimensions should be passed to `nearest_neighbor` as arguments.

Comment: This would be a useful approach if the actual matrix size were being read from the file... but in this case apparently the file format has a fixed size.