# Calling external function with parameter that is an array c++

Tags: c++, arrays, function, vector

I don't know if it is possible to create a function which has a parameter that is an array. I have this:

main.cpp

```
#include "nn.h"

int main()
{ n=30;
float distance[n][n];
nearest_neighbor(distance);  
}
```

nn.h

```
  #ifndef _nn_H // must be unique name in the project
  #define _nn_H

  std::vector<std::vector<float>> nearest_neighbor(float distances); 

  #endif
```

nn.cpp

```
  int n=30
  vector<vector<float>> nearest_neighbor(float distances[n][n])
   { Some code
    }
```

How can I pass the distances matrix to an external function?

Comment: stack can overflow with medium sized matrices with that parameter. Why not passing only pointer?

Comment: Function signature should be the same in header and source files, so in `nn.h` use `std::vector<std::vector<float>> nearest_neighbor(float distances[30][30]);` as well.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik Can you explain me how to passing  pointer??

Comment: @triple_r I´ve already tried that but I get the error "undefined reference  to nearest_neighbor(float(*)[30])"

Comment: @Eli, Yes, for the same reason as [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28616823/passing-2-d-array-to-function-gives-strange-error). `float[30][30]` is not the same as `float[n][n]` unless `n` is a compile-time constant with the value 30.

Comment: double pointer / pointer to pointer?

Comment: @chris I defined n as int const=30;

Comment: @Eli if you're passing a *real* array of arrays (not a faux pointer-array) the stride of all inferior dimensions below the most superior *must be known at compile time*. You can whip up a template function that will handle this for you by deducing the array of arrays dimensions, but again, those dimensions *must be known at compile time*.

Comment: Example of my prior comment: [see it live](http://ideone.com/oS7UDi).

Comment: @Eli as chris said, you need to make sure that `n` is known in compile time. Best way to do that is to define it as a constant `constexpr int n = 30;`.

Comment: @WhozCraig Doing that means create function nearest_neighbor in the same cpp file where I call it???